# Compile inside a compile inside a compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

I have multiple custom directives that compiles the html inside of them. The problem is that the highest "layer" runs/executes everytime a compile is being made.

The stack is something like this

- directive_a

  - directive_b

    - directive_c

      ```
      <directive-a>
         <directive-b>
           <directive-c>
             <div ng-controller="Controller">
               <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
             </div>
           </directive-c>
         <directive-b>
      <directive-a>
      ```

The directive_c is being executed 2 times and if it has some let's say constructor it reinitialize as many as compilations are being made.

The goal to be acieved is render every directive once.

How can i solve this?

Comment: it's not really clear what you are meaning here.  It's *extremely rare* to need to use `$compile`, and even rarer that you would ever have a use case that would involve nesting `$compile`.  can you describe a bit about what you are actually trying to accomplish with these various directives?

Comment: i have a scrollbar component that compiles the content inside, inside i have another component that compiles the code inside, and the final actual content gets executed twice..

Comment: that sounds like normal behavior for the way that `$compile` works;  perhaps you could show some code from these directives that may help people suggest alternatives to using `$compile`.